# Application is crashing when using data model migration in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm trying to figure out how to make my app to be able to migrate from one data model version to another.

I read whole bunch of resources online, and figured out that using Magical Record can be really useful, especially MR_coordinatorWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed method.

Everything looked good until I started to do some testing, when I noticed the app crash under following conditions.

[image]

so this is my data model versions...everything works just fine when I work with document version or document4 version...but when I pick document3 version I have this crash:

[image]

any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The error is telling you its trying to merge from more than one model and that the VideoInfo entity is different in each model.  Check you don't have another model included in your app's bundle somewhere.

Comment: well...I am trying to migrate models, if you noticed from my screenshot I do have 3 different versions of the model, and indeed the VideoInfo entity is changed...but as I said the error occurs ONLY when I use versions that's between the first version and the last one

Comment: Yes I saw that, but do you have another model not just different versions of the model shown above, that is somehow included in the app bundle. Open the compiled app bundle and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use migrations, you have to manually create your data model from the .momd bundles. So for your managedObjectModel accessor method that gets created in your application delegate you need to change it slightly from what gets implemented by default:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }

    // modified method
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"VideoInfo" ofType:@"momd"];
    NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];

    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

There's a great explanation of this [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/09/core-data-migration-problems.html).

Comment: I'm actually doing it...and it doesn't explain why I can easily load the very first and the very last version of my data model, and get my app working, but none versions from between seem to be working properly